# Custom contrasts in piecewise mixed effects models

Tags: lme4-nlme, interaction, contrasts, piecewise-linear

I have longitudinal data from a two-group RCT in which the primary outcome was assessed at baseline, each week during the intervention, post-test and 5-month follow-up (6 times total). I am modeling the data in R (lme4) as a piecewise mixed effects model with T1 - T5 (post-test) change modeled as a random slope (first piece) and t5 to follow-up modeled as a fixed effect (second piece). Time is nested within participant and labeled 1 through 6. I coded time in the first and second pieces as:

```
df$piece1 <- car::recode(df$time,"1=-4;2=-3;3=-2;4=-1;5=0;6=0")
df$piece2 <- car::recode(df$time,"1=0;2=0;3=0;4=0;5=0;6=25")
```

The model is:

```
mod1 <- lmer(value ~ 1 + piece1*group + piece2*group+ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 +
               (1 + piece1 | sid),
             data = df)
```

I realize there are different ways to model these data but settled on a piecewise model for reasons I will not go into here. The coefficient for piece1*group represents the pre- to post-test by group interaction. The coefficient for piece2*group represents the post- to follow-up by group interaction. My question is, how do I construct a contrast to extract from this model the pre- to follow-up by group interaction?

To get the coefficient of this interaction, I can multiply `piece1*group` by 5 and `piece2*group` by 25 and add them together (see my coding of the splines above), but to get the p-value, I need the se and I'm not sure how to get calculate/find it. I am hoping there is a way to set a contrast that will allow me to get the coefficient of this effect and it's se and p-value.